# Is printf("%s", *string) possible?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, printf

My professor told me to make a program which reads names, ages, antiquity and docket of X quantity of people, and when it's done, print it on a table-like format. For all of that, I have to have 2 separate functions. One that reads what the user inputs, and other that outputs everything the user inputted in a table like format.

Now, the problem is that when I try to print the gathered info, it only prints the first character of every "slot" on the array. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define sfb if(db[i][0][0] == 17 || db[i][1][0] == 17 || db[i][2][0] == 17 || db[i][3][0] == 17){break;}

void read();
void printt(char *, int);

int main(){
    read();
    return 0;
}

void read(){
    char db[20][4][20];
    memset(db, 0, sizeof db);
    printf("Ingrese ^Q para salir\n");
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        printf("Ingrese nombre de persona: ");
        fgets(db[i][0], sizeof db[i][0], stdin);
        db[i][0][strcspn(db[i][0], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
        printf("Ingrese legajo de %s: ", db[i][0]);
        fgets(db[i][1], sizeof db[i][1], stdin);
        db[i][1][strcspn(db[i][1], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
        printf("Ingrese edad de %s: ", db[i][0]);
        fgets(db[i][2], sizeof db[i][2], stdin);
        db[i][2][strcspn(db[i][2], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
        printf("Ingrese antiguedad de %s: ", db[i][0]);
        fgets(db[i][3], sizeof db[i][3], stdin);
        db[i][3][strcspn(db[i][3], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
    }
    printt(&db[0][0][0], i);
}

void printt(char *dbp, int slots){
    system("cls");
    printf("%-30s|%-20s|%-7s|%-10s\n", "Nombre", "Legajo", "Edad", "Antiguedad");
    for (int i = 0; i < slots * 80; i = i + 80){
        printf("%-30c|%-20c|%-7c|%-10c\n", *(dbp+i), *(dbp+i+20), *(dbp+i+40), *(dbp+i+60));
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

Now, I have to clarify that I know that I'm using `%c` instead of `%s`  in the `printf()`(Ln 48), but if I put `%s`, it won't compile, and it will give me the next error, 4 times:

```
format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Werror=format=]
```

I know that this happens because with the pointer, I'm only referencing to the first element of the array. My question is if there is anything that can tell the `printf()` to print where the pointer tells, and X (20) places more. In my mind I imagine something like this:

```
printf("%-30s|%-20s|%-7s|%-10s\n", *(dbp+i)[20], *(dbp+i+20)[20], *(dbp+i+40)[20], *(dbp+i+60)[20]);
```

I also know that I can use `for()` loops, to print each field, character by character, but I dont like how that looks :/

If there is no such thing as what I imagined, I'll be stuck to use the `for()` loop method.

Comment: You need to pass `db` to `printt`, not `db[0][0][0]`. The former is the address of the whole "database" and the latter is a pointer to one character within it. And, of course, you need to declare the corresponding `printt` parameter correctly.

Comment: @JeffHolt, I've tried using `&db` and `db`, and both give me this error: `passing argument 1 of 'printt' from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]` Can you explain me a little bit more?

Comment: Without checking the return value of `fgets()`, code is weak.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica what do you mean? I only need `fgets()` to extract the value of `stdin`. What else can be done?

Comment: @fpp Code does not know `fgets(...., stdin)` succeeded without checking the return value. Input can fail if `stdin` is at end-of-file or due to input error.  e.g. `if (fgets(db[i][0], sizeof db[i][0], stdin) == NULL) { puts("Fail"); exit(-1); }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to dereference the pointer, and you can pass `dpb[0][0]` rather than the address of `dbp[0][0][0]`.

You might want to look into using `struct`s instead of multi-dimensional arrays, it'll make the logic a lot simpler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define sfb if(db[i][0][0] == 17 || db[i][1][0] == 17 || db[i][2][0] == 17 || db[i][3][0] == 17){break;}

void read();
void printt(char *, int);

int main(){
    read();
    return 0;
}

void read(){
    char db[20][4][20];
    memset(db, 0, sizeof db);
    printf("Ingrese ^Q para salir\n");
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        printf("Ingrese nombre de persona: ");
        fgets(db[i][0], sizeof db[i][0], stdin);
        db[i][0][strcspn(db[i][0], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
        printf("Ingrese legajo de %s: ", db[i][0]);
        fgets(db[i][1], sizeof db[i][1], stdin);
        db[i][1][strcspn(db[i][1], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
        printf("Ingrese edad de %s: ", db[i][0]);
        fgets(db[i][2], sizeof db[i][2], stdin);
        db[i][2][strcspn(db[i][2], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
        printf("Ingrese antiguedad de %s: ", db[i][0]);
        fgets(db[i][3], sizeof db[i][3], stdin);
        db[i][3][strcspn(db[i][3], "\n")] = 0;
        sfb;
    }
    printt(db[0][0], i);
}

void printt(char *dbp, int slots){
    system("cls");
    printf("%-30s|%-20s|%-7s|%-10s\n", "Nombre", "Legajo", "Edad", "Antiguedad");
    for (int i = 0; i < slots * 80; i = i + 80){
        printf("%-30s|%-20s|%-7s|%-10s\n", (dbp+i), (dbp+i+20), (dbp+i+40), (dbp+i+60));
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
}
```